# the time tense (had now been detected)

Tags: meaning, grammar

Thank so much for your help.

I found the following sentence in a newspaper this morning:

> "The virus had now been detected in 23 countries in the Americas," she added.

Is the sentence's verb "had now been detected" involved with time from the past to now? Or totally past? It seems to be a very difficult sentence for me:(

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. For future questions, I'd like to advise you to visit our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), but please make sure you take the [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit their [Help Center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) before posting any question. Please don't post the same question on ELL.

Comment: Use capital letters where you should. Once you've copied and pasted something, make sure everything's in the right place. I have no idea what a "he virus" is. And don't use "emoticons," or whatever the f**** they are, please. In other words, do have some respect for those whom you expect to assist you.

Comment: @Ricky You're the one showing disrespect here.  You know better than this.

Comment: I am sorry for my mistake. It doesn't mean that. I am an English beginner. Really sorry again.

Comment: @deadrat: Your Grace, I thought I was rising as one, standing up for the high principles and morals of EL&U. Darn, I can't do anything right today. Next round's on me, everyone. Libiamo, libiamo ne'lieti calici ...

Comment: You don't have to say sorry. Your first question was migrated to English Language Learners. [with you or to you](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/80132/with-you-or-to-you).

Comment: @Ricky I don't mind your standing up for the questionable principles and standards of EL&U.  If you wish to instruct the ignorant on the proper use of capitals and emoticons, fine.  I suppose that nobody has actually got to do it, but fine, anyway.  My objection is to accusing a low rep user of disrespect when you have no evidence of that.

Comment: @deadrat: I protest I never actually disrespect people. I have excellent manners and know some French.

Comment: @deadrat Being nice to a low rep user is one thing (I agree and sorry I was also rude to new users from time to time) and answering such a poor quality question is another. This question doesn't belong here. It is borderline on-topic on ELL, too.

Comment: @Rathony First of all, let me acknowledge that you have a point about the question.  But that's a separate issue from my admonition to Ricky.  If you feel this question doesn't belong here, I trust you voted to close it.    My sympathy for ELLs is larger than my concern for the sanctity of ELU, but I do appreciate that you've phrased a valid concern in terms of the question and not in terms of my moral failing.  At least that way i don't feel like I'm being stalked.

Comment: @Rathony I don't think backshift is a borderline topic for ELL, although it probably could be marked as a duplicate there, although a rep 1 user would be unlikely to find the answer on ELL even if she knew the term *backshift*.

Comment: @deadrat I am getting tired of voting to close it and I never vote to migrate it to ELL (I don't know why, but I just vote to close such a question as lack of research or something else). As a matter of fact, I didn't close-vote this question. I think time has come for me to leave ELU or take a break for a while and focus more on running and learning. :-)

Comment: @Rathony Dealing with recalcitrant people like me can be tiring.  If you need a break to recharge, by all means take it.  If you do, I'll miss your contributions while you're gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to get your quotes straight.  I believe this is actually from the newspaper *The Guardian* and is actually a [quote plus a paraphrase](http://www.pressreader.com/uk/the-guardian/20160129/281487865374166/TextView) of the words of Margaret Chan, the director of WHO [World Health Organization], words that she spoke at an emergency meeting:

> It was "deeply concerning" that the virus had now been detected in 23 countries in the Americas, she added.

This is report of past speech.  We can tell because "added" is past tense.  We may infer that Ms. Chan said at the time of the meeting:

> "It is deeply concerning that the virus has now been detected in 23 countries in the Americas."

When the newspaper reports on this meeting after it happened, the tenses must be transposed to past time.  This is called backshift.  The present tense "is" becomes the past tense "was," and the present perfect "has been detected" becomes the past perfect "had been detected."